# Is it possible for a webPage to detect when it is open in a IOS UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like detect if my web page is visualize with a UIWebView in a IOS app. Is it possible ? How ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Differentiate it using the user Agent, in mobile-safari the user-agent string contains the word safari the webView doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for the User-Agent from the HTTP header. However I am not sure it you can differentiate between a page being displayed in mobile safari and a web view.

Comment: The user agent is different between UIWebView and Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UIWebViewDelegate protocol to check the Http requests.

Answer (score 0):

the best way I have found to detect not only what device, but also the device capabilities. Is using device atlas

http://deviceatlas.com/

They have an extremely definitive list of the User agents as well as the associated device capabilities. Such as what types of media they can support as well as what the screen resolution is.

If you are wanting an all encompassing way to detect mobile devices, they have got you covered.